# How to create External Panels in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to create a multi page application and am using JQuery mobile,  I have couple of Panels using jQuery mobile:

```
<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-theme="b" data-display="overlay"></div>
<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-display="overlay" data-position="right" data-theme="b"></div>
```

However, It would be cumbersome to add these panels to every page I create.
So I need help in using these panels in all the pages I'm about to create.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this demo: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/ If you view source you will see that you simply need to initialize the panels $( "body>[data-role='panel']" ).panel().enhanceWithin();

Comment: thanks for the reply! This worked for me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110638/jquery-mobile-multiple-external-panels/29174402#29174402

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", ".demo-page", function() {
var panell = '<div data-role="panel" id="left-panel" data-position="left" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="index.html" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li><li><a href="bio.html" data-transition="slide">About</a></li><li><a href="news.html" data-transition="slide">News</a></li></ul></div>';
$.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panell);
$("#left-panel").panel().enhanceWithin();

var panelr = '<div data-role="panel" id="right-panel" data-position="right" data-display="reveal" data-theme="a"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="index.html" data-transition="slide">Home</a></li><li><a href="bio.html" data-transition="slide">About</a></li><li><a href="news.html" data-transition="slide">News</a></li></ul></div>';
$.mobile.pageContainer.prepend(panelr);
$("#right-panel").panel().enhanceWithin();
});
```